# How to apply same conditional formatting on all columns in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using conditional formatting in a google sheet.
I can apply this format to a specific column without issue.
But if I want to have the same format on all columns with each column being independent of the other, I don't know what range I should use.

When I set a range that takes applies it to all the columns, the conditional formatting is checking the content of all the cells across all the columns instead of checking the all the cells of each column separately.

I don't know if it's clear, basically, I want to each column formatted separately.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using app script to generate the data in my sheet, I used the conditionalFormatRule builder object : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder

It works like a charm.
But indeed, if I were to manually input data in the sheet, I would have to manually set the conditional formatting on each column... which is completely crazy.

Thank you anyway player0 !

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you need to set up conditional formatting per each column separately (manually). So for columns A-Z you will have in total 26 conditional formatting rules in your spreadsheet per your sheet.